# Datatables shared parameters affected by sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I have a DataTable that can have N number of children DataTable(s) that can be added/removed/recreated at any time. I would like the children to share initialization parameters but it seems that DataTables affect the original data structure.

When adding two children and sorting the first one, the second child will inherit the sorting when recreated. I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wthY9/44/

```
var myDataTable;
var index = 0;
var parentParams = {
    "order":[],
    "columns":[
        {"name":"Col 1"},
        {"name":"Col 2"},
        {"name":"Col 3"},
        {"name":"Col 4"},
    ],
};
var childParams = {
    "columns":[
        {"name":"Col 1"},
        {"name":"Col 2"},
        {"name":"Col 3"},
    ],
        "order":[],
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    myDataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable(parentParams);

    $('#createChild').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(typeof myDataTable.row(index).child() == "undefined"){
            var $table = $($('#child_table').html());
            $table.css('width','100%');
            var newChildParams = $.extend({}, childParams);
            var childTable = $table.DataTable(newChildParams);
            myDataTable.row(index).child(
                childTable.table().container()
            );
        }
        myDataTable.row(index).child.show();
        index++;
    });

-    $('#recreateChild').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var lastIndex = index - 1;

        var $table = $($('#child_table').html());
        $table.css('width','100%');
        var childTable = $table.DataTable(childParams);
        myDataTable.row(lastIndex).child(
            childTable.table().container()
        );

        myDataTable.row(lastIndex).child.show();
    });

    $('#hideChild').click(function(e){
        myDataTable.row(--index).child.hide();
    });
});
```

Steps:

1. Add two children
2. Sort first child on any column
3. Recreate the second child with the recreate button
4. Second child have inherited the ordering (debugging shows that the default childParameters now have ordering set instead of being an empty Array).

How can I recreate children and keep the sort order for the child being recreated?

Edit: Since there has been no answer nor comment I have double posted this question to the [DataTables forum](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28193/how-to-use-shared-default-parameters-for-keeping-order-in-datatables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var newChildParams = $.extend({}, childParams);` is shallow copy here, which means `newChildParams` only point to `childParams`'s address. If you change the variable in `newChildParams`, `childParams` will update too.

The solution is use deep copy `var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);`. It will copy the object to another memory address. You can see [the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/184780/4968420) for more details.

So I edited deep copy to `#createChild` and `#recreateChild` in your code, you can see demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wthY9/45/).

Comment: Ah, of course. So if I wanted to keep the sort order when table is recreated I would have to store the settings object in some map or array to be able to re-set the order argument. What would you suggest?

Comment: I would use array with shallow copy, see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wthY9/46/). I added `ChildOptionsArray` and you can search this keyword to see some differences.